# Quality option with -write in ImageMagick

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I am using the CLI of imagemagick to export cropped images of a unique picture:

```
convert -quiet a.jpg -write mpr:uniquePicture \( mpr:uniquePicture -crop 10x10+5+5 +repage -write b.jpg +delete \) null:
```

In my script there are a lot of "\( \)" with different crop parameters.

This works perfectly but I would like to control the quality of the exported picture ("b.jpg" in my example). If I had "-quality 90" inside the "\( \)" there is an error…

So, is there a way to use the jpg quality inside the "\( \)"?

Thierry

Comment: What error do you get, please? Also, please show the *exact* command that caused the error. And your **IM** version. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me on IM 6.9.12.50 Q16 Mac OSX Monterey.

```
convert -quiet lena.jpg -write mpr:uniquePicture \( mpr:uniquePicture -crop 10x10+5+5 +repage -quality 90 +write lena_sub.jpg +delete \) null:
```

I suspect there is something wrong with your command line. But also what is your Imagemagick version and platform.

Note I have use +write, but -write works also. I generally use +write to avoid any issues with format confusion.